# Extraneous argument label 'number:' in call

Tags: swift

While I was learning about "Functions", I met an issue showing "Extraneous argument label 'number:' in call" error msg for my code. I wonder why I shouldn't place "number" in argument?

```
func makeIncrementer() -> ((Int) -> Int) {
    func addOne(number: Int) -> Int {
        return 1 + number
    }
    return addOne
}
var increment = makeIncrementer()
increment(number: 7)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rF88z.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're returning a `(Int) -> Int`, which doesn't specify a name for its argument. Ideally, you'd want to write

```swift
func makeIncrementer() -> ((number: Int) -> Int)
```

but that isn't allowed in Swift:

```
function types cannot have argument labels; use '_' before 'number'
```

The best you can do is

```swift
func makeIncrementer() -> ((_ number: Int) -> Int)
```

This strategy might make your code a little clearer because giving the argument a name makes its purpose more obvious. Unfortunately, you still have to omit the `number:` label when you call the returned function:

```swift
let increment = makeIncrementer()
increment(7)  // <- no `number:` label
```

---

#### What's the rationale?

Specifying argument labels for function types was possible before Swift 3. The problem was that you could write

```
func add(numToAdd: Int) -> Int { ... }
func subtract(numToSubtract: Int) -> Int { ... }

let f: ((numToAdd: Int) -> Int) = subtract
```

and then calling `f(numToAdd: 3)` would actually call `subtract(numToSubtract: 3)`, which is quite surprising and can cause confusion.

Check out [this proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/545e7bea606f87a7ff4decf656954b0219e037d3/proposals/0111-remove-arg-label-type-significance.md) for the full rationale behind removing this feature.